# Viewing multiple markers on map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, markers

I'm trying to view multiple markers on the map, so I did this but unfortunately didn't work, any one would tell me where the error is? I'm using JavaScript.

```
        var studentAddresses = [
            [37.1, -78.024],
            [37.5, -78.044],
            [37.9, -78.064]
        ];



        add.locations.forEach((studentAddresses) => {
            // add marker to map
            var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                .setLngLat([studentAddresses[0][0], studentAddresses[0][1]])
                .setPopup(popup)
                .addTo(map);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over whatever is in add.locations…
If you want to loop over studentAddresses the forEach loop should look like this

```js
studentAddresses.forEach((address) => {
            // add marker to map
            var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
               marker.setLngLat([address[0], address[1]])
                .setPopup(popup)
                .addTo(map);
    }
)
```